# Integration of Jira with Testlink

Tags: tools, testlink, jira

Does anyone know how to fix the integration with Jira when you want to create an issue in Testlink?
I attached the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshoot]

Comment: Could you provide some more information about what you've done to integrate? The screenshot doesn't give any information except that there's an error somewhere.

Comment: The screenshoot above is happened when I click create issue button in Test Execution menu in testlink. It should be added issue in jira automatically. But I found this window and Not issue added in JIra.

Comment: I have tried with Jira version 4.4.4. And now, I am success to integrate issue from testlink to Jira with Jira version 6. Is it all about version in Jira?

Comment: Does anyone know, its all about version in Jira or another cause?